# How to temporarily lock a Dropbox folder from all other users

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, dropbox, shared-folders

I am in a situation where I must work on a code project with 1 or 2 other people who are unwilling to use a revision control system like git. They insist on using Dropbox instead. I'm searching for a method to ensure that we never have conflicts. I need to find a way to ensure that 2 people never work on the Dropbox project at the same time.

My first instinct is to just rename the folder every time I work on it, but that doesn't seem very safe or error proof. Is there a solution that would allow me to lock all other users with access to a Dropbox folder out of the folder temporarily?

Comment: This is a management problem, not a software one. You've already seen that in your own question 'doesn't seem very safe or error proof.' The only hope you have is that dropbox keeps file revisions to save you some pain. They'll learn their lesson once it screws up however.

Comment: @djsmiley2k yeah, I'm very aware it's a management problem, but it's completely out of my hands at this point. I've tried every approach I could  think of to get our small company to adopt something like git, but it has become apparent recently that it is impossible for the time being. Therefore, I'm looking for the next best option at this point.

Comment: I can only wish you luck then!